# How to "rotate" swap matplotlib.pyplot.imshow axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

This might be a bit too stupid, but I'm new to python and I'm struggling with something simple that I couldn't find a solution to yet.

I have the following code, which gives me the image just below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DATA_PATH = Path.cwd()

df_full_irradiation = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH / 'solar_avg.csv')
df_GHI = df_full_irradiation[['Day', 'Month', 'Hour end', 'GHI [Wh/m2]']]

solar_1D = np.array(df_GHI['GHI [Wh/m2]'])
number_quarters = 96
number_days = int(solar_1D.shape[0]/number_quarters)
solar_2D = solar_1D.reshape(number_days, number_quarters)

plt.imshow(solar_2D, cmap='hot')
plt.xlabel('Time of day')
plt.ylabel('Day of year')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D54u8.png)

This gives me a plot where my horizontal axis is the time of day, and the vertical the day of the year. I would like to make the horizontal axis the days, and the time of day in vertical, but when I invert the arguments on reshape the plot gets destroyed.

Would anyone know how to fix this? :)

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried solar_2D.T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
# [...]
plt.imshow(solar_2D.T, cmap='hot')
plt.ylabel('Time of day')
plt.xlabel('Day of year')
# [...]
```

Comment: Mignificent! :O
So simple... I didn't know that! Thank you!! :)